# Tesseract working with XCode

Tags: c++, tesseract

I wish to use Tesseract with OpenCV on a C++ project (**not iOS**) I'm working, but I'm unable to get Tesseract to work with XCode. I've added the .dylib files for Leptonica and Tesseract and it works fine, but then I get the following error when I run the APIExample program

`read_params_file: parameter not found: save_raw_choices`

If I do not add the .dylib files and try adding the header files obtained through Homebrew, I get the following error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"tesseract::TessBaseAPI::GetUTF8Text()", referenced from:
tesseractTest() in main.o
"tesseract::TessBaseAPI::End()", referenced from:
tesseractTest() in main.o
```

I'm a little inexperienced with development in Mac OS X.

Comment: Hi vignesh, I also want to build tesseract with OpenCV on c++ project(In Xcode)(not iOS).I googled lot but i am not satisfied .so how to build tasseract for c++ project (from download to  create .dylib file for both leptonica and tesseract).Please give me step by step answer.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same problem and found only this remark on google groups:
http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/issues/detail?id=990

Basically, just use different tessdata - e.g. download spanish and set it as language. It would pass that step and show some results. Though they were not splendid in my case but at least you will see it working:).

Then I would recommend asking at the project google group for help...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I didn't include the tesseract c flags and libraries when compiling.

if you add this to your cflags: `pkg-config --cflags tesseract`

and this to your libs: `pkg-config --libs tesseract`

then it should compile.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question but I didn't found anythink online and after hours I solved this issue by adding the line (-ltesseract) to the Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags in xCode